# Changing the name of a field displayed in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, datagridview

How can I change the name of the fields displayed in a `DataGridView` in `C#`? I am using a `SQLite Database`.

Here's my Code:

```
const string filename = @"database.db";
const string sql = "select * from legal_tbl;";
var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + filename + ";Version=3;");
try
{
   conn.Open();
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   var da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, conn);
   da.Fill(ds);
   DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
   this.data_view.DataSource = dt;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex + "");
}
```

But, it's displaying the name of the field in the database. I want to change it.
Ex. `id_num => ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating the HeaderText property of the column:

```
this.data_view.Columns["id_num"].HeaderText = "ID";
```

Comment: I don't know why this is not working. Maybe, i placed that code incorrectly. BTW, i-pasted inside the try-catch block

Comment: @user3569641 Make sure you set it *after* you set the grid's DataSource.  The column wouldn't exist beforehand.  If that isn't the issue, then the column name might not be matching.

Answer (score 0):

LarsTech's answer is the one I'd use but as an alternative you could alias the columns in your select:

```
const string sql = "select id_num as ID, [etc...] from legal_tbl;";
```